# Cannot upgrade to 4.0 - get SSL certificate error

Tags: errors, ssl

I am not a developer. I have a blog. I don't understand code.

I am trying to update my site to 4.0 from 3.5.1 version but kept getting an SSL certificate error. I was told by my hosting service provider that it is a Wordpress error and that they cannot assist except recommend a workaround. I then added the following lines as requested in order to update but then received a new error on my dashboard: could not copy files.

Please assist me in getting my site back online. It is a blank screen right now.

[image: SSL error image]
[image: lines added]
[image: cannot copy files error]

Comment: The last error isn't related to the SSL issue. Did your hosts install WordPress for you? You could try asking them about that one, but without more information about how you're hosted it's difficult to know what to recommend: it's probably just the wrong file permissions or the wrong file ownership, but I don't know the auto update mechanism well.

Comment: The SSL issue is arguably WordPress's fault, but it's actually the website wordpress.org not the WordPress software you're running: it's SSL certificate chain is four long and the server doesn't include both middle certificates in the handshake. However your web browser won't have any problems because the missing one is commonly bundled nowadays: you could say that this is as much your web hosts's fault by not having up-to-date widely accepted intermediate CA certificates installed on their system. But I doubt they'd see it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is your hosting company fault. The underlying library that performs the authentication that you are actually connecting to wordpress.org is probably missing some related configuration to be able to complete correctly the authentication.

The solution they gave you is not secure and while I don't believe anything bad will happen because of that it is a good reason to start suspecting the security practices of the company and maybe look for a better one.

As fr the second part, you didn't give/have the right permission to the upgrade process to be able to write to the directory where your wordpress is installed. If you don't understand file permission issues then you ask the support to check them for you.